# Dockerize next.js and nginx at one Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, next.js

i've successfully dockerize my app using two docker image, one for nginx and second for the app and it runs well because i use docker compose.
Now i only want to have just one Dockerfile that contain app and nginx then run it on my local computer. How i could achieve that?

This is my `nginx/default.conf`

```
# Cache zone
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

upstream nextjs {
  server nextjs:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  server_tokens off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  # BUILT ASSETS (E.G. JS BUNDLES)
  # Browser cache - max cache headers from Next.js as build id in url
  # Server cache - valid forever (cleared after cache "inactive" period)
  location /_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs;
  }

  # STATIC ASSETS (E.G. IMAGES)
  # Browser cache - "no-cache" headers from Next.js as no build id in url
  # Server cache - refresh regularly in case of changes
  location /static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs;
  }

  # DYNAMIC ASSETS - NO CACHE
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://nextjs;
  }
}
```

My /nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine as build
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

/Dockerfile [old]

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN npm install --global pm2
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
USER node
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

and this is the new Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN npm install --global pm2
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
COPY ./ ./
# Build app
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
USER node
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/app/.next /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/log
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I can build it, but whenever i run the image will throw error
**host not found in upstream "nextjs:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:5**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks to @octagon_octopus
I finally solve this problem by changing my nginx/default.conf

my Dockerfile

```
# build react app, it should be /build
# FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
FROM node:13-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --only=prod
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# Creating nginx image and copy build folder from above
# FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/buffer
COPY --from=build /app/.next /usr/share/nginx/buffer
COPY --from=build /app/deploy.sh /usr/share/nginx/buffer
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/buffer/deploy.sh
RUN cd /usr/share/nginx/buffer && ./deploy.sh
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/log
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and nginx/default.conf

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/pages;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/pages;
  }
  error_log /usr/share/nginx/log/error.log warn;
  access_log /usr/share/nginx/log/access.log;
}
```

Comment: Good that it works now. I assumed you were running a nodejs application, but looks like nextjs is something different, my bad. Serving your web application through an nginx container is the correct approach as you do right now.

Comment: COPY --from=build /app/deploy.sh /usr/share/nginx/buffer . Can you paste code for deploy.sh

Comment: @otniel could you please share deploy.sh?

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGautam sorry i'm not use that config anymore. Now my app only have one docker image and serve at kubernetes

Comment: yeah, how did you put both containers in one docker image and use it in Kubernetes I have the same issue now.

Comment: @otniel, so can you provide the updated config then? Please do update the solution for nextjs+nginx. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @otniel wouldn't be good to share the deployment.sh with us? Since you asked for help from the community perhaps it's good to share that last piece of lego puzzle in order to be clear for all us others.

Regards.

Comment: I also meant how do you run nuxt.js server inside nginx within the same Dockerfile, would like to elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get `host not found in upstream "nextjs:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:5` is because according to your `nginx/default.conf`, nginx will forward all received requests to `http://nextjs`. This worked before, because you probably had node running in a separate container called `nextjs`. Now you try to run nginx and node in the same container, so the `nextjs` container does not exist anymore and nginx has nothing to forward requests to.

It seems to me that you are trying to run a reverse proxy and node application within the same container, when running them in two separate containers should be more desirable like you had it before.

If you are just developing your node app locally, you won't need the nginx reverse proxy and you can just send requests to the node app directly, so only the node container is needed. When you deploy to production, you typically use something like an nginx reverse proxy for various reasons like SSL termination and load balancing. In that case you can deploy the nginx and node containers together.

If you really want to continue with your current approach,  then you will probably have to forward the requests to `http://localhost` instead of `http://nextjs`, although I don't think that will be the only problem. Node is probably not running within your container either. You start the Node application with `CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]` in a multi-stage docker build and that node image will be discarded. You will have to start your Node application inside the nginx container instead.

Comment: hi, thanks for your explanation. I can understand now. i've made some change to  my dockerfile and nginx/default.conf and it run well.